# VisualStudioCode: Limit intellisense completions of words to be case sensitive

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, case-sensitive

is there a way to limit IntelliSense completions in VisualStudioCode to match the case of a Word in the code?

E.g. if the code contains both
   house, House
and I start typing "ho" I want to get only "house" as completion and not "House". Likewise, if I start typing "Ho" I should be getting only "House" as a possible completion and not "house".

Thank you for all your help.

Kind regards,
Seppix